# Compilation errors with spark cassandra connector and SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cassandra, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to get the DataStax spark cassandra connector working. I've created a new SBT project in IntelliJ, and added a single class. The class and my sbt file is given below. Creating spark contexts seem to work, however, the moment I uncomment the line where I try to create a cassandraTable, I get the following compilation error:

**Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in CassandraRow.class refers to term catalyst
in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling CassandraRow.class.**

Sbt is kind of new to me, and I would appreciate any help in understanding what this error means (and of course, how to resolve it).

```
name := "cassySpark1"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.1.0" withSources() withJavadoc()

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.1.0-alpha2" withSources() withJavadoc()

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

And my class:

> import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
>
> import com.datastax.spark.connector._
>
> object HelloWorld {   def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
>       System.setProperty("spark.cassandra.query.retry.count", "1")
>
> ```
> val conf = new SparkConf(true)
>   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandra-hostname")
>   .set("spark.cassandra.username", "cassandra")
>   .set("spark.cassandra.password", "cassandra")
>
> val sc = new SparkContext("local", "testingCassy", conf)
> ```
>
> ***>     //val foo = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace name", "table name")***
>
> ```
> val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
> val sum = rdd.reduce(_+_)
>
> println(sum)   } }
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `spark-sql` to dependencies list

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.1.0"
```

Comment: yup...that was it. seems like the docs are a bit out of date. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add library dependency in your project's `pom.xml` file. It seems they have changed the `Vector.class` dependencies location in the new refactoring.